# logback SiftingAppender generated log files cannot be deleted untill stop the tomcat server

Tags: java, file-io, logback, tomcat8

We are using logback "SiftingAppender" for generating the log files based on the date and other information such as cycle(Each date can have multiple cycles).

Following are the sample logging file names

20150515_1_Job1.log
20150515_2_Job1.log

For the above scenario we are using the following logback configuration.

```
<appender name="BATCH_LOGGER_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>batchLoggerFileName</key>
        <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>${batchlog.dir}/${batchLoggerFileName}.log</file>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | [%thread] | %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<logger name="BATCH_LOGGER" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="BATCH_LOGGER_APPENDER"></appender-ref>
</logger>
```

Following is the java code for logging the details to the specific logs files.

```
private static final Logger BATCH_LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger("BATCH_LOGGER");

public void info(JobInfo jobInfo, String message) {
    MDC.put("batchLoggerFileName", jobInfo.getJobId());
    BATCH_LOGGER.info(message);
    MDC.remove("batchLoggerFileName");
}
```

We have some other jobs that do the housekeeping of the old log files with the retention of 2 days(Two day old files will be moved to another location).

But even after the job completes, we are not able to move the file.
We suspect that logback is holding the resource and not letting the file to move or delete.

All the jobs are deployed in a single war file in apache tomcat 8 server.

Can anyone suggest how to enforce logback to release the resource after logging is completed?

Regards,
Mayuran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the suggestion suggested by logback support in there support group when i asked this question.

> Mayuran,
>
> You can add FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER to the MDC to trigger the
>   sub-appender to be cleaned up.  This is documented in
>   http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html
>
> Once you do that the sub-appender goes into lingering state for 10
>   seconds, then the appender will be closed after that.
>
> Dave

Comment: you may copy an truncate original files (on linux), works if the file is still oppen